# Trouble with the password hashing and salting

Tags: python, django, authentication, web

I'm trying to implement a login system for my web application, but I'm having trouble with the password hashing and salting. My current code is generating different hash values for the same password, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue? Here is the relevant code:

```
import hashlib
import random

def hash_password(password):
    salt = random.randint(0, 1000000)
    hashed_password = hashlib.sha256((password + str(salt)).encode()).hexdigest()
    return (hashed_password, salt)

password = 'password123'
hashed_password, salt = hash_password(password)
print(hashed_password)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And it should, you are adding a salt as a random number generator. `salt = random.randint(0, 1000000)`, it will also change if you use a different hashing algorithm.

Comment: When password is created you use the random salt, and save it, to use the same salt when verifying the password.